# Python socket to webserver with parameters with POST

Tags: python, http, post, request

I have to receive a flag from my professor's website by getting the token from my username and using that token to access the actual flag. We can only use Socket to make requests from the server and the token only lasted for 2 seconds so I had to put them in a script.
I managed to find the token with this code (won't show the website for safety reasons):

```
import socket
import re

target = the_web_site
port = 82
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print(target)
client.connect((target, port))

request = ( "POST /getSecure?user=myusername HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
            "Host: %s\r\n" +
            "\r\n"
          ) % target
print(request)
client.send(request.encode())

respone = client.recv(4096)
print(respone.decode())
splitted = respone.decode().split('"token":')
token = splitted[1].strip('"')[:-3]
```

One of the example for token look like this :
{"token":"369e1ae6a49ac8c453c3c8af15c863a71bf5789e11eab15667f733eb"}

And then I tried to use the token that I split and strip for the flag that I'm looking for:

```
request = ("POST /getFlag2?user=my_user_name&token=%s HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
           "Host: %s\r\n" +
           "\r\n"
           ) % (token, target)
client.send(request.encode())
```

The response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 29 Jan 2022 02:12:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 41
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

You must provide a token to this endpoint
```

I wonder if I messed up putting in the user and the token by using "&". Is there anything else I could try?

update:
Trying Authentication Bearer:

```
request = ("POST /getFlag2?user=my_user_name HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
           "Host: %s\r\n" +
           "Authorization: Bearer %s\r\n"
           ) % (target, token)
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 408 Request Timeout
Date: Sat, 29 Jan 2022 03:36:57 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 298
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>408 Request Timeout</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request Timeout</h1>
<p>Server timeout waiting for the HTTP request from the client.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at 172.18.0.10 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

I fixed the problem with the token param not being passed in by :

```
request = ("POST /getFlag2?user=my_user_name HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
           "Host: %s\r\n" +
           "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" +
           "Content-Length: 64\r\n" +
           "\r\n" +
           "token=%s\r\n"
           ) % (target, token)
```

But now the session key is invalid. Sed life

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a value for `Authorization` with value `Bearer *your token here*`.

```
request = ("POST /getFlag2?user=my_user_name HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
           "Host: %s\r\n" +
           "Authorization: Bearer %s\r\n"
           ) % (target, token)
client.send(request.encode())
```

Comment: I got the 408 error from it: Server timeout waiting for the HTTP request from the client.

Comment: Hmm... are there any API specs for the getFlag endpoint?

Comment: The token variable is just the actual token data, right? (e.g., token = "3926a...")

Comment: I don't think so, but I put the token param into the body with content type and content length and it passed onto the server now! But now you got the error wrong session :(

Comment: At least we got this issue solved. One to the next one. Good luck!